# establishing a win streak in dice game

Tags: python, dice

> Hi all. Really, REALLY stuck here.  I've updated my code below.
>   I'm trying to establish a counter to track games played, correct guesses and > incorrect guesses plus, when the number of consecutive correct guesses
>   = 4 or user stops playing, game summary is provided.
>   I cannot get the counter to work correctly.
>   Help appreciated!

```
import math
import dice
import random

# Print introduction and game explanation
print ("")
print ("")
print ("Would you like to play a game?")
print ("The game is...'Petals Around the Rose'. Cool eh?")
print ("Pay attention - the name of the game is important.")
print ("Each round, five dice are rolled and")
print ("You'll be asked for the score. (Hint? The score")
print ("will always be either 'zero' or an even number).")
print ("Your challenge is to deduce how the computer has")
print ("calculated the score.")
print ("You need to input your guess, after which")
print ("You'll learn if you were right. If not, you'll")
print ("be told the correct score & asked to roll again.")
print ("If you can guess correctly four times in a row,")
print ("You'll be declared the winner and receive the")
print ("majestic title of 'Potentate of the Rose'")
print ("")

# Define win count (four correct guesses in a row required)
win_count = 0

# Obtain input from user:    
answer = input("Are you up for the challenge? Enter 'y' or 'n' : ")
# If answer = no, exit game
if answer == 'n':
    print("Really? fine then. See ya!")
    exit()
# If answer = yes, commence game
elif answer == 'y':
    print("")
    print ("Ok...here comes the first roll!")
    print("")
    # import dice representation
    import dice

# Roll random dice x 5
die1 = random.randint(1, 6)
die2 = random.randint(1, 6)
die3 = random.randint(1, 6)
die4 = random.randint(1, 6)
die5 = random.randint(1, 6)
dice.display_dice(die1, die2, die3, die4, die5)


# Obtain player's guess for the roll
roll_guess = int(input("Enter your guess for this roll: "))

# Define die results for all dice for guess purposes to
# match the 'petals around the rose'. So, if roll a 2, 4 or 6,
# the result is zero. If return a 3, the result is 2. If
# return a 5, the result is 4.
def roll_result(die1):
    if die1 == 1 or die1 == 2 or die1 == 4 or die1 == 6:
        die1 = 0
    elif die1 == 3:
        die1 = 2
    elif die1 == 5:
        die1 = 4
    return die1
def roll_result(die2):
    if die2 == 1 or die2 == 2 or die2 == 4 or die2 == 6:
        die2 = 0
    elif die2 == 3:
        die2 = 2
    elif die2 == 5:
        die2 = 4
    return die2
def roll_result(die3):
    if die3 == 1 or die3 == 2 or die3 == 4 or die3 == 6:
        die3 = 0
    elif die3 == 3:
        die3 = 2
    elif die3 == 5:
        die3 = 4
    return die3
def roll_result(die4):
    if die4 == 1 or die4 == 2 or die4 == 4 or die4 == 6:
        die4 = 0
    elif die4 == 3:
        die4 = 2
    elif die4 == 5:
        die4 = 4
    return die4
def roll_result(die5):
    if die5 == 1 or die5 == 2 or die5 == 4 or die5 == 6:
        die5 = 0
    elif die5 == 3:
        die5= 2
    elif die5 == 5:
        die5 = 4
    return die5
# tally all 5 dice rolls
a = roll_result(die1)
b = roll_result(die2)
c = roll_result(die3)
d = roll_result(die4)
e = roll_result(die5)
total_roll_result = a + b + c + d + e

# Compare user input to dice result
if roll_guess == total_roll_result:
    print("")
    print('Well done! You guessed it!')
    print("")
elif guess % 2 == 0:
    print("")
    print("No sorry, it's", total_roll_result, "not", roll_guess)
    print("")
else:
    print("")
    print ("No, sorry, it's", total_roll_result, 'not', roll_guess,"")
    print ("Remember,the answer will always be an even number")
    print("")

# Obtain user input if continuing to play    
another_attempt = input("Are you up to play again? If so, enter y or n ")
print("")
# Commence loop and win count. 
while another_attempt == 'y' and win_count <4:
    # Commence win count
    win_count = 0
    # Commence games played count
    games_played = 0
    # Commence incorrect guesses count
    incorrect_guesses = 0
    # If user has not yet gotten 4 guesses in a row:
    if win_count < 4:
        die1 = random.randint(1,6)
        die2 = random.randint(1,6)
        die3 = random.randint(1,6)
        die4 = random.randint(1,6)
        die5 = random.randint(1,6)
        result = dice.display_dice(die1, die2, die3, die4, die5)
        a = roll_result(die1)
        b = roll_result(die2)
        c = roll_result(die3)
        d = roll_result(die4)
        e = roll_result(die5)
        total_roll_result = a + b + c + d + e
        roll_guess = int(input('Enter your guess for this roll: '))
        print("")
        if roll_guess == total_roll_result:
            # Update win count
            win_count += 1
            # Update games played count
            games_played += 1
            print("")
            print('Nice work - you got it right!')
        elif roll_guess %2 == 0:
            # reset win count
            win_count = 0
            # Update games played count
            games_played += 1
            # Update incorrect guesses count
            incorrect_guesses += 1
            print("")
            print("Nah, sorry, it's", total_roll_result, "not", roll_guess)
        else:
            # Reset win count
            win_count = 0
            # Update games played count
            games_played += 1
            # Update incorrect guesses count
            incorrect_guesses += 1
            print("")
            print ("Nah, sorry, it's", total_roll_result, 'not', roll_guess,"")
            print ("Remember,the answer will always be an even number")
        print("")
        another_attempt = input("Are you up to play again? ")
        # Quit loop if user no longer wishes to play
        # Provide game summary
        if another_attempt == 'n':
                print ("")
                print ("Game Summary")
                print ("------------")
                print ("")
                print ("You played ", games_played, "games.")
                print ("")
                print ("You had ", correct_guesses, "overall and ")
                print ("")
                print ("a total of ", incorrect_guesses, "overall ")
                print ("")
                print ("Cheerio!")
                exit()
    if win_count == 4:
        # Inform player has correctly guessed 4 in a row
        # Print congratulations message
        print ("")
        print ("")
        print ("You've done it! You've successfully guessed")
        print ("Four times in a row. Looks like you worked ")
        print ("out the secret. Now, stay stum & tell no one!")
        print ("")
        # Provide game summary
        print ("Game Summary")
        print ("")
        # Provide tally of games played & print:
        print ("You played ", games_played, "games.")
        print ("")
        # Provide tally of correct guesses & print:
        print ("You had ", correct_guesses, "overall and ")
        print ("")
        # Provide tally of total incorrect guesses & print:
        print ("a total of ", incorrect_guesses, "overall ")
        print ("")
        print ("Cheerio!")
        exit()

def game_stats():
    win_count
    games_played
incorrect_guesses
```

Comment: Why do you define `roll_result` five times? You know only the last definition counts right?

Comment: You also need to tell us more specifically which part doesn't work.

Comment: Hi @iamvegan, I thought it had to be set up that way to determine the roll result for each die (also, it helped clarify my own thought process).

Comment: Re the incorrect code part, I'm looking specifically at the section:

Comment: def win_count():
        win_count() == 0
        correct == total_roll_result
    while win_count <= 4:
        if roll_guess(correct):
            win_count += 1
        else:
            win_count = 0
        if win_count == 4:
            print ("You keep getting this right!")

Comment: I can't figure out how to get the game count to work!

Comment: Why do you have `win_count = 0` inside your `while another_attempt == 'y' and win_count <4` loop?

Comment: Bloody Hell. @iamvegan - ignore the last comment. I actually edited it after going back & reviewing where I'd placed the win count & realised what you meant; I'd put it in twice. It all works perfectly now!  Thanks again for your help, so very much appreciated!

Comment: Good! I was hoping you would realize that!

Answer (score 1):

You look very lost here. This part does not make any sense

```
def win_count():
    win_count() == 0
    correct == total_roll_result
```

I think you mean something like this

```
win_count = 0
correct = total_roll_result == roll_guess
```

**Note**

When you say

```
def win_count:
   # some code
```

you are defining `win_count` as a function! But clearly you want `win_count` to be an integer counting something.

Comment: Hi @iamvegan    - tried your suggestion....am I just placing this section in the wrong section overall?  'while keep_playing == 'y':'   
        'win_count = 0'
        'correct = total_roll_result == roll_guess'
        'while win_count < 4:'
            'if correct:'
                'win_count +=1'
            'else:'
                'win_count = 0'
            'if win_count == 4:'
                'print ("You keep getting this right!")'

Comment: @YVB It's hard to read long code in a comment, but yes that's where you put my suggestion. What do you think doesn't work now? You need to go over your code very carefully. There are many logic errors. Try writing short pieces of it and make sure they work.

Comment: thanks @iamvegan! You may've given me the tools to work this out now. From what you're saying, if I break this up piecemeal, then rewrite in smaller sections, checking as I go (& rather than making it all, effectively, under the loop section) I should be right! Thank you so much!

Comment: @YVB yes. It looks like you want to write a code that lets the user play again and again in a loop. Maybe you can write a code that plays this game only once. That would be a good benchmark.

Comment: Oh, the game code part was relatively simple. Including a loop was also easy. the difficult part was breaking the loop once they had gotten the answer correct so many times in a row, hence the need for a counter.

Comment: @YVB The loops with `while keep_playing == 'y':` are not correct.

Comment: @YVB I can have a look if you can include the current version of your code in your post. Also please tell me what kind of error you are still getting with the counter.

Comment: @ iamvegan - I've restarted the code from scratch and edited the post to match the updated code. I can't get the counters to work though - it doesn't recognise: a) when reaches 4 consecutive guesses and as a result, b) can't generate the game stats.